# How do I prevent caching of my FUSE file?

Tags: python, fuse

How do I prevent the OS (or whatever is doing it) from caching the size/contents of a file in my FUSE filesystem?

I've made a small, reproducing example that creates a file system with a single file `/foo`.  The contents of `/foo` change every 5 seconds.  Here's my FUSE filesystem (`sample.py`):

```
import sys
import time
import errno
from stat import S_IFDIR, S_IFREG
from fuse import FUSE, LoggingMixIn, Operations, FuseOSError


class MyFS(LoggingMixIn, Operations):

    now = time.time()

    def getattr(self, path, fh=None):
        if path == '/':
            return dict(st_mode=(S_IFDIR | 0755),
                        st_ctime=self.now,
                        st_mtime=self.now,
                        st_atime=self.now,
                        st_nlink=2)
        elif path == '/foo':
            contents = self.fooContents()
            now = time.time()
            return dict(st_mode=S_IFREG,
                        st_nlink=1,
                        st_size=len(contents),
                        st_ctime=now,
                        st_mtime=now,
                        st_atime=now)
        else:
            raise FuseOSError(errno.ENOENT)

    def readdir(self, path, fh):
        if path == '/':
            return ['.', '..', 'foo']
        else:
            raise FuseOSError(errno.ENOENT)

    def open(self, path, flags):
        return 0

    def read(self, path, size, offset, fh):
        if path == '/foo':
            return self.fooContents()[offset:offset+size]

    def fooContents(self):
        t = int(time.time())
        size = (t / 5) % 10 + 1
        ret = ''
        for i in xrange(size):
            ret += str(i % 10)
        return ret + '\n'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mountpoint = sys.argv[1]
    FUSE(MyFS(), mountpoint, foreground=True)
```

If I `cat` the contents every second for 10 seconds, I expect to see 2 or 3 different contents printed out, but instead I see the same contents 10 times:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do
>   cat /tmp/dump/foo
>   sleep 1
> done
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
```

If I `ls -al` prior to catting the file, I get what I would expect:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do
>   ls -al /tmp/dump >> /dev/null
>   cat /tmp/dump/foo
>   sleep 1
> done
01234567
01234567
01234567
01234567
012345678
012345678
012345678
012345678
012345678
0123456789
```

How can I get the output of the second shell commands while running the first shell commands?

Comment: It looks like passing `direct_io=True` to the `FUSE(` call will prevent caching.  It seems to prevent caching universally.  It would be nice to be able to prevent caching on a file-by-file basis.

Answer (score 3):

just put to procedure *open* these lines

```
st = fuse.FuseFileInfo()
accmode = os.O_RDONLY | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_RDWR
if (flags & accmode) != os.O_RDONLY:
  return -errno.EACCES
setattr(st,'direct_io',True)
#setattr(st,keep,False)
return st
```

If you do not need cache a file - switch direct_io to True.